# Возврат результата функции Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, json, for, return, yield

У меня функция записывает результат парсинга в файл с помощью json. После чего мне нужно прочитать файл, извлечь все данные и отправить результат на сайт.

Когда я возвращаю результат функции с помощью return, читается только первая строка и renurn останавливает выполнение функции, помогите выйти из ситуации - как можно вернуть все данные из файла (если использовать print, все воркает и я получаю весь список):

```
        with open("DJ.json", "w", encoding="utf-8") as file:
            json.dump(content, file)
            print('Запись прошла успешно')
            file.close()

        with open("DJ.json", encoding="utf-8") as file:
            data = json.load(file)
            return data
```

Файл можно посмотреть по ссылке - https://www.dropbox.com/s/tn0ev9hjbgl9b0f/DJ.json?dl=0

Прочитал, что yield может помочь в данном вопросе, но у меня не выходит его применить.

И у меня попутно есть еще один вопрос, как возвращать данные из цикла?
Буду благодарен за помощь.

Comment: its work on my machine

Comment: http://prntscr.com/pqsppw